# undefined method `paginate' for #<PG::Result:0x007f8f096a3390 (Converting arel result)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following method:

```
@vulnerabilities = Vulnerability.details(filter_version_param, 
                     filter: filter,
                   sort: order)
                     .paginate(page: page_param, per_page: 10)
```

The internals of this method uses arel to find the relevant information to display on a page. However when I run into the `.page` method from the `will_paginate` gem, I receive the following error:

```
`undefined method `paginate' for #<PG::Result:0x007f8f096a3390>`
```

This is due of course to the fact that the object returned is not a class from ActiveRecord. My question is whether there is a way to convert the PG class into an ActiveRecord model? A previous implementation on the application from another developer creates a `Struct.new()` class and feeds the values into it. I was wondering though if there was an easier way to do this.

Comment: it looks like the `details` function is not returning an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, try doing the `paginate` call first.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the problem. The paginate method cannot be called on the `PG::Result`. It has to be converted to a relation. I'm wondering if there is a way to instantiate it.

Comment: can you call the `details` function on the results of `paginate`?

Comment: The result is `undefined method `total_pages' for #<PG::Result:0x007f8efaad9270>` on `paginate`

Comment: you could convert this to an array and include `will_paginate/array`. Maybe something along the lines of `@vulnerabilities = Vulnerability.details(filter_version_param, 
                     filter: filter,
                   sort: order); @vulnerabilities.values.map {|row| row.zip(@vulnerabilities.fields).to_h }.paginate(page: page_param, per_page: 10)`

Comment: yes, `array` pagination might help, can you confirm `to_a` returns an array of your `result` object? `Vulnerability.details(filter_version_param, filter: filter, sort: order).to_a`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- for `Kaminary gem as an example` : convert the query result into an 
     array and use `Kaminary.paginate_array(array_of_result).page(#pagenumber).per(#elemnts per page)`, but this way could have problems with large data tables since you need to load the hole table for example, then slice the page!
- you can build an object that has the sufficient methods needed for the paginator to do its job.

for more explanation and information about the above two points, please chick this [link](http://iempire.ru/2015/11/08/kaminari-custom-query/).